# How to Return Specific HTTP Status Code in a Plain HTML Page

Tags: html, apache, http

Google recommends returning a 503 HTTP response when a site is temporarily unavailable.

I have a few plain HTML Sites. How do I return 503 status in plain HTML sites?

I'm on a Linux box with Apache.

Comment: Check this answer on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/53061/how-can-i-return-a-503-status-in-apache-without-invoking-external-scripts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the status code on the sever and not in your HTML files.

Comment: Exactly. If the server is able to send HTML files to the user, it is not temporarily unavailable by definition!